# Calculating adjoint operator for standard inner product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

> Let $V=M_2(\mathbb R )$ with $ \left\langle A,B \right\rangle
>  =\operatorname{tr}(B^tA)$. Define  $$ T\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\c& d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3d& 2c\\-b& 4a\end{pmatrix}. $$ Find
>   $T^\ast$.

**My attempt:** Using the usual isomorphism $[-]_\beta:M_2(\mathbb R)\cong \mathbb R^4$ defined by $\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\c& d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto (a,b,c,d)^t$, let $[T]_\beta$ be the representing matrix of $T$ w.r.t the standard basis $\beta$. Let $G$ be the Gramian. Then

$$ \left\langle TA,B \right\rangle = \left\langle G[TA]_\beta,G[B]_\beta \right\rangle_\mathbb{R^4}=\left\langle G[T]_\beta[A]_\beta,G[B]_\beta \right\rangle_\mathbb{R^4}=\left\langle G[A]_\beta,G[T]_\beta^t[B]_\beta \right\rangle_\mathbb{R^4}$$
Let $T^\ast$ be the operator with $[T^\ast ]_\beta=[T]_\beta ^t$. Then
$$\left\langle G[A]_\beta,G[T]_\beta^t[B]_\beta \right\rangle_\mathbb{R^4}=\left\langle G[A]_\beta,G[T^\ast]_\beta[B]_\beta \right\rangle_\mathbb{R^4}=\left\langle G[A]_\beta,G[T^\ast B]_\beta \right\rangle_\mathbb{R^4}=\left\langle A,T^\ast B \right\rangle.$$
So if I understand correctly, all I need to do is find $[T]_\beta^t$ and I'm done. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but note that since you were asked to find the operator $T^{*}$ and not its matrix representation, you need to go back and write the formula for $T^{*}$ similarly to how the formula for $T$ was given to you.

Comment: Okay, I got $T^\ast\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\c& d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4d& -c\\2b& 3a\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: @linalg: Looks good.

Comment: I've just realized I can't justify the third equality I wrote. Why is it true?

Comment: I don't know which "third" equality you refer for. Anyway, since the basic matrices $e_{ij}$ for an orthonormal basis for $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and your isomorphism sends them to the standard basis vectors $e_j$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$, you get an isomorphism of inner product spaces. That is, $\left< v, w \right>_V = \left< [v]_{\beta}, [w]_{\beta} \right>_{\mathbb{R}^4}$. If you represent an operator on a real inner product space with respect to an orthonormal basis by a matrix then the adjoint operator is represented by the transpose of that matrix.

Comment: I'm referring to the equality $\left\langle G[T]_\beta[A]_\beta,G[B]_\beta \right\rangle_\mathbb{R^4}=\left\langle G[A]_\beta,G[T]_\beta^t[B]_\beta \right\rangle_\mathbb{R^4}$. Why does it hold? As you write: "If you represent an operator on a real inner product space with respect to an orthonormal basis by a matrix then the adjoint operator is represented by the transpose of that matrix.", but then I should look at $G[T]_\beta$ transpose and not just ignore the presence of $G$ there... Did I explain myself well?

Comment: I would also say that your second equality doesn't hold. What is true is that $\left< v, w \right> = [v]_{\beta}^t G [w]_{\beta}$. But there is no reason to talk about the Gramian for this exercise since it is the identity anyway...

Comment: I [asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851491/matrix-representing-inner-product) my question, if you'd like to answer :)